# Is the pkt_data occupies memory continuously?

Tags: wireshark, winpcap, sniffer

I am developing sniffer using WinPcap. As am running application continuously, after 6 hours RAM is becoming full and it is not responding. why the memory increasing continuously?
Is `const u_char* pkt_data` is occupies memory each time?
Which variable is occupying memory continuously in Pcap API's? if so how to free the memory?

Comment: There's no memory to free in pcap under normal circumstances. It's more likely your code is doing something wrong that's causing this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is `const u_char* pkt_data` is occupies memory each time?

No.  The memory pointed to by `pkt_data` is not guaranteed to remain allocated after your callback routine returns (if you're using `pcap_loop()` or `pcap_dispatch()`) or after the next call to `pcap_next()` or `pcap_next_ex()`.  In WinPcap, [there's a fixed-size circular buffer into which packets are placed in the kernel](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__NPF.html), and those are read into a single fixed-size buffer in the library.

> Which variable is occupying memory continuously in Pcap API's?

None.  As nos indicates, it's probably a memory leak in your program.